# How do I fetch text from discord web block embed

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So here is the deal, i'm having trouble picking up a certain type of message content (not sure of its name) and I can't seem to figure this out no matter how much I look into the Internet since I can't find any information on this

[image: Message]

Using my current code, I can perfectly detect normal text (the blue one) however text inside that block I can't seem to fetch, these blocks appear as a part of a URL posted on a message

My current code:

```
async def on_message(message):
    messagecontent = message.content
    if 'test' in messagecontent:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'success')
```

As I said, this works for normal text inside a message but not for text inside the block, so I was hoping someone here could help me in figuring this out

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Message.embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)

It returns a dict inside an array so for your Google example it would return

```
[{'url': 'https://www.google.com//', 'type': 'link', 'title': 'Google', 'description': "Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for."}]
```

So to access the "description" you could do something like

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.embeds:
        print(message.embeds[0]['description'])
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much, this is really useful. Im not used with working with arrays so would you know how to put the content of title into a string so I can work with it? Thank you once again!

Comment: Sure, you can just do `title = message.embeds[0]['title']` and now you have a string variable with the title of an embed